# Combine year and month

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 dropdowmlists where its aspx code is

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlexpyear" runat="server" Width="50px" TabIndex="4"
                   DataTextField="" DataValueField="" AppendDataBoundItems="true"           
                   ValidationGroup="userinfo" DataSourceID="objectdatasource1" 
                   onselectedindexchanged="ddlexpyear_SelectedIndexChanged">
      <asp:ListItem Value="-1">--- Please select ---</asp:ListItem>                       
 </asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="(Year)"></asp:Label>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlexpmonth" runat="server" 
        AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="objectdatasource2"
        DataTextField="" DataValueField="" TabIndex="4" 
        ValidationGroup="userinfo" Width="50px" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddlexpmonth_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <asp:ListItem Value="0">--- Please select ---</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="(Month)"></asp:Label>
 <sup style="color: Red;">*</sup> </td>
```

Here if i select `year as 2` and  `month as 5` I `want to save it as 2.5`. And if i i select `year as 3` and `month as 9` i `want to save it as 3.9` and like that.

Please help me to solve this.

Good suggestion is appreciable.

Comment: in `Label4` and `Label5` display the `ddl` `selected value` am i right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this by two way

(1) One way using `dropdownlist` `SelectedItem` propety

```
lbltest.Text = ddlexpyear.SelectedItem.Text + "." + ddlexpmonth.SelectedItem.Text;
double test = Convert.ToDouble(lbltest.Text);
```

(2) Another way using `dropdownlist` `SelectedValue` propety

```
 lbltest.Text = ddlexpyear.SelectedValue + "." + ddlexpmonth.SelectedValue;
 double test= Convert.ToDouble(lbltest.Text);
```

If google then you have definitely find out.

I hope it's help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to simply `combine` the selected values and then convert it to `Double`.

```
lblSave.Text = ddlexpyear.SelectedItem.Text + "." + ddlexpmonth.SelectedItem.Text;
double save = Convert.ToDouble(lblSave.Text);
```

And if you have `DataValueField` then:

```
lblSave.Text = ddlexpyear.SelectedValue + "." + ddlexpmonth.SelectedValue;
double save = Convert.ToDouble(lblSave.Text);
```

Comment: ok thank you @Vishal Suthar
I will try it and reply u whether its working.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this way:

```
protected void ddlexpyear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label4.Text = ddlexpyear.SelectedValue + "." + ddlexpmonth.SelectedValue;
} 
protected void ddlexpmonth_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label4.Text = ddlexpyear.SelectedValue + "." + ddlexpmonth.SelectedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do following.
If you are not setting `"datavaluefield"` and `"datatextfield"` code side, then set both parameters.
In Datavaluefiled you should put parameter which need to be saved (eg. 1,2,3) and datatextfield should be the value which need to be shown to user in dropdown (e.g January, february,...)

On save do following.

Check if none of both is set to index `-1`.
There should be any non-negative integer value.

```
string Savevalue =  `ddlExpYear.selectedvalue.toString() + "." + 
.selectedvalue.tostring()`
```

Hope it would help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting why this became a problem to you!

```
string year=ddlexpyear.SelectedValue.ToString();
string month=ddlexpmonth.SelectedValue.ToString();
string TotalExp=year + "." + month;
```

This should solve your problem